# How to extract the specific part of text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, database

[image: Image of a text file, I am working on]

I have big data as shown in the uploaded pic, it has 90 BAND-INDEX and each BAND-INDEX has 300 rows.
I want to search the text file for a specific value like `-24.83271` and extract the `BAND-INDEX` containing that value in an array form. Can you please write the code to do so? Thank you in advance

I am unable to extract the specific `BAND-INDEX` in array form.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file line by line and using a `generator`. Here is an example:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd


# generate and save demo csv
pd.DataFrame({
    'Band-Index': (0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06),
    'value': (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
}).to_csv('example.csv', index=False)


def search_values_in_file(search_values: list):
    with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        reader.__next__()  # skip header
        for row in reader:
            band_index, value = row
            if value in search_values:
                yield row


# get lines from csv where value in ['4', '6']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(search_values_in_file(['4', '6'])), columns=['Band-Index', 'value'])
print(df)
#  Band-Index value
# 0       0.04     4
# 1       0.06     6
```